# How to play two consistently video in html?

Tags: html, html5-video

Hi in my requirement i want to play two video one after another.i want to play them consistently. for this i am using this code.

```
    <html>
<div class="video_player">
     <video width="100%" height="auto" id="video" controls >
                            <source src="<%=videoPath1%>" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="<%=videoPath2%>" type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
</div> 
   </html>
```

But it is not working can anybody please give me a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should only list the first video.   The ability to list several is to accommodate different formats because different browsers support different formats.

Second add some javascript to respond to the "ended" event.  Within the video tag add onended="swapVideos();", assuming your javascript function is called swapVideos().

In the swapVideos() function,

1. Find the video tag
2. Get the sources element
3. Change the src value to the other video
4. Issue a load command against the video object